# How to Read data from JSON in Oracle 11g

Tags: json, plsql, oracle11g

Dear All i have made the following code in order to get the API response in json which is working fine and returning the json now i want to read the json output and display on the Oracle 11g form can anyone help?

```
DECLARE
  req     UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  resp    UTL_HTTP.RESP;
  content VARCHAR2(4000);
  buffer  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN        
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST (
    url    => 'http://demo-piaic-server.herokuapp.com/api/v1/findVoucher',
    method => 'POST'
  );

  content := '{'
    || '"fee_voucher_no":"' || 329 || '",' -- remember to escape special characters  
    || '"apikey":"' ||'zKoJSEVJdrld0g59pqpCOveBOBf46iYOHYbOOdUX'|| '"'
    || '}';

  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER( req, 'content-type', 'application/json' ); 
  UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER( req, 'Content-Length', length(content) );
  UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT( r => req, data => content );
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

  BEGIN
    LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE( resp, buffer, TRUE );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( buffer );
    END LOOP;
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
      UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
  END;
END;
```

Output

```
{"statusCode":"001","success":true,"rollNo":"PIAIC40","quarter":"Q1","fee_voucher_no":329,"fullName":"Akmal Elahi Shaikh"}
```

Comment: You probably want to put the response in a table with a JSON constrained column, and query it from there if you want to extract individual elements of the JSON payload.

Comment: @acroyear pretty sure that JSON constrained columns were not introduced till 12c and the tag says 11g

Comment: Good point @ShaunPeterson

Comment: I have previously used pljson to parse JSON when using 11g. It might be worth having a look at it on github to see if it would work for you: https://github.com/pljson/pljson

Comment: You can also try APEX if it works for you: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/tips-for-parsing-json-in-apex